# Issue with buttons and textboxes

Tags: vba, userform, wordle-game

I'm trying to create a wordle game but I'm not sure how to display strings textbox when button is clicked. For example, in this

[image: screenshot],

when letter "A" is clicked, the first row of the first textbox will display "A". If letter "B" is clicked, the first textbox will display "B" etc. I want to make it so that it can spell out a word using the buttons and textboxes(grid). I tried

```
 tb1.text = cmdbtn1.caption
```

but I didn't get the expected result. I'm not sure if I have to use for loop to do so. Please give some suggestions. Thanks.

This is one of the button events that is used throughout the program

```
Private Sub cmdbtn1_Click()
  'code here
end sub
```

Comment: Which event is being used? Please share code in your post.

Comment: I have put my comment underneath. Not sure if you can see it

Comment: Please do not add comments as answers - instead, just edit your question to include the code.

Comment: You need to describe what you want to do in greater detail.  Do you want to change the text of the active control to the button caption?

Comment: It's like when you're typing on a keyboard but instead clicking the buttons on the keyboard, like windows keyboard. Then, the letters will be displayed in the first row of the textboxes. When the enter button is clicked, it will tell you which word is in the right place/right position or right word/wrong position.

Comment: @taller So I have 26 buttons with 20 textboxes at the top. I want to make it like a keyboard press so that each button click triggers each textbox. The name of the textbox is tb1,tb2,tb3 to tb20

This is one of the button events that is used throughout the program
```Private Sub cmdbtn1_Click()
  'code here
end sub```

Comment: Do you want to change only the selected textbox value?

Comment: yeah I think so. The buttons and textboxes have to be related like what I said earlier. If one(button) clicks, the other(textbox) has to have the same value

Comment: Should the next textbox automatically be selected?

Comment: yes that can do

Comment: You can edit your question using the Edit button just below the tags at the bottom of your question (have added the code from your deleted comment/answer).

Comment: You'd preferably have each btn send their caption to a general Sub that'll check which textbox to fill in.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I just knew and did it but thanks..

Comment: @Notus_Panda yes that's what I want in the result

Answer (score 0):

We need to track the active Textbox.  If all the controls directly on the Userform, the Userform's ActiveControl changes to the Button when it is clicked.   We could track the active Textbox using each Textboxes' Exit event.

```
Private ActiveCheckbox As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub tb1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Set ActiveCheckbox = tb1
End Sub

Private Sub tb2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Set ActiveCheckbox = tb2
End Sub
```

But this is a lot of extra work.  Alternately, we can place all the textboxes in a Frame control.  The Frame's ActiveControl will not change when a Button outside of the Frame is clicked.

[image: Userform Example]

We also need call a subroutine to process the button clicks.

```
Private Sub UpdateWordleTextbox(btn As MSForms.CommandButton)
    If IsNull(Frame1.ActiveControl) Then Exit Sub
    If Not (Frame1.ActiveControl.Name Like "tb#" Or Frame1.ActiveControl.Name Like "tb##") Then Exit Sub
    Frame1.ActiveControl.Value = btn.Caption
    
    Dim CurrentTextBoxIndex As Long
    CurrentTextBoxIndex = Replace(Frame1.ActiveControl.Name, "tb", "")
    
    If CurrentTextBoxIndex = 20 Then CurrentTextBoxIndex = 0
    CurrentTextBoxIndex = CurrentTextBoxIndex + 1
    
    Frame1.Controls("tb" & CurrentTextBoxIndex).SetFocus
    
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  UpdateWordleTextbox CommandButton1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  UpdateWordleTextbox CommandButton2
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
  UpdateWordleTextbox CommandButton1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
  UpdateWordleTextbox CommandButton1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I have an error that says 'Object variable or with block variable not set' in this line 
```If Not (Frame1.ActiveControl.Name Like "tb#" Or Frame1.ActiveControl.Name Like "tb##") Then Exit Sub``` after putting the frame in

Comment: @sera Is there a Frame named Frame1?  Here is the file that I used [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ZiMy5vZQ3KPBq0rdg8RJDmrndnw1I9-/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Yeah I didn't change the name of the frame

Comment: Does it affect the code if i use 'cmdbtnQ' or 'cmdbtnT'?

Comment: You should watch teh [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) on YouTube.  My code used the default CommandButton names.  The event names must match the control names.  See [Excel VBA Introduction Part 20.1 - Event Procedures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EXdPcbsTZI&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=22)

Comment: Idk why it won't work on my program